# ValueError: Invalid characters in query string with twitter streaming API

Tags: python, twitter

I get

```
ValueError: Invalid characters in query string
```

error when i use the twitter streaming API to make the following query.

```
search_query = u"emmy awards, ios 7"
streaming_url = u"https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track={}".format(search_query)
```

However, if I give in just one argument for the track parameter like `ios 7` everything goes fine. Is there something wrong in the way I am encoding the parameters? Because according to the twitter API [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#track), it does support a comma separated list of arguments for the track parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to encode the query from:

```
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=emmy awards, ios 7
```

to:

```
https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=emmy%20awards%2C%20ios%207
```

You can use [`urllib.quote`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) for this:

```
In [1]: import urllib

In [2]: search_query = u"emmy awards, ios 7"

In [3]: urllib.quote(search_query)
Out[3]: 'emmy%20awards%2C%20ios%207'

In [4]: streaming_url = u"https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?rack={}".format(urllib.quote(search_query))

In [5]: streaming_url
Out[5]: u'https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?rack=emmy%20awards%2C%20ios%207'

In [6]:
```

Comment: Yikes! I think I was not encoding the commas! Thanks @BSH